# PowerShell Behaviour for return from Function

Tags: powershell, hashtable, return-value

I've a simple CSV file. It contains Header and some values. Generally it works fine if there are more then 2 entries in the CSV file. If there is only 1 entry (and Header) it behaves very unexpected to me.

```
function ImportServersToProcess($csv) {
    begin {
        [System.Collections.ArrayList] $aServers = @()
    } 

    process {
        $ImportedData = Import-CSV $csvPath -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Hostname','ServiceIP','AdminIP','IBRIP','HW','VMHW','OS','CPUs','RAM','DriveSizeC','DriveSizeD'
        ForEach ($item in $ImportedData){
            [System.Collections.Hashtable] $hServer = @{}

            $hServer.Hostname = $($item.Hostname)
            $hServer.ServiceIP = $($item.ServiceIP)
            $hServer.AdminIP = $($item.AdminIP)
            $hServer.IBRIP = $($item.IBRIP)
            $hServer.HW = $($item.HW)
            $hServer.VMHW = $($item.VMHW)
            $hServer.OS = $($item.OS)
            $hServer.CPUs = $($item.CPUs)
            $hServer.RAM = $($item.RAM)
            $hServer.DriveSizeC = $($item.DriveSizeC)
            $hServer.DriveSizeD = $($item.DriveSizeD)

            if ($hServer.Hostname -eq "Hostname") { continue } # Ignore 1st line/headers
            $aServers.Add($hServer) | Out-Null # OutNull is used to prevent additonal add to array of unexpected object (also suprising output)
        }
        Write-Host "Test0 - " $aServers.Count
        $aServers #| Out-Null
        Write-Host "TEST1 - " $aServers.Count
    }
    end {
    }
}
```

CSV looks like this:

```
Hostname;ServiceIP;AdminIP;IBRIP;HW;VMHW;OS;CPUs;RAM;DriveSizeC;DriveSizeD
ash000126;1.1.1.191;2.2.2.223;3.3.3.223;System x;Virtual: 01_CL_01;Windows 2012 R2 ;4;16;200;300
ash000127;1.1.1.191;2.2.2.223;3.3.3.223;System x;Virtual: 01_CL_01;Windows 2012 R2 ;4;16;200;300
```

Then I run the script using:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $aServersToProcess = ImportServersToProcess($csvPath)
[int] $count = $($aServersToProcess.Count)
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[*] There are $count servers to be checked. Starting up [*]"
```

Output on screen is:

```
Test0 -  2
TEST1 -  2
[*] There are 2 servers to be checked. Starting up [*]
```

Which is good. 2 servers in CSV. 2 Counts.

Now if I remove 1 server from CSV and CSV now looks like this:

```
Hostname;ServiceIP;AdminIP;IBRIP;HW;VMHW;OS;CPUs;RAM;DriveSizeC;DriveSizeD
ash000126;1.1.1.191;2.2.2.223;3.3.3.223;System x;Virtual: 01_CL_01;Windows 2012 R2 ;4;16;200;300
```

Be aware there are no empty lines etc.

The return of the script is...

```
Test0 -  1
TEST1 -  1
[*] There are 11 servers to be checked. Starting up [*]
```

Where does 11 come from?

If I modify the script and add $aServers.Count behind $aServers

```
Write-Host "Test0 - " $aServers.Count        
$aServers 
$aServers.Count
Write-Host "TEST1 - " $aServers.Count
```

The output is this:

```
Test0 -  1
TEST1 -  1
[*] There are 2 servers to be checked. Starting up [*]
```

Comment: Side note: you are not using $csv parameter in your function.

Comment: return `,$aServers` rather that `$aServers`

Comment: Ha! You are correct Mathias... please provide answer and explanation if possible :-)

Comment: Good read: Keith Hill's Effective Powershell Item 8 (look for text on unary comma): https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/

Comment: @dugas Thanks, it was using global value. I would prefer PowerShell to complain a bit about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 11 is coming from the number of headers in the CSV.  This is an issue where you are getting a single object, vs. a collection with more than one entry in the csv.

I'm thinking the best solution here is going to be to typecast $ImportedData as an array, so that if there is only one element it becomes a collection, not an object.

```
$ImportedData = @(Import-CSV $csvPath -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Hostname','ServiceIP','AdminIP','IBRIP','HW','VMHW','OS','CPUs','RAM','DriveSizeC','DriveSizeD')
```

That is one simple way to accomplish this.  Another way is:

```
[Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$ImportedData = Import-CSV $csvPath -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Hostname','ServiceIP','AdminIP','IBRIP','HW','VMHW','OS','CPUs','RAM','DriveSizeC','DriveSizeD'
```

Edit:
As it turns out, it looks like the issue is actually in your return, and when there is only one object in the output, it is being received as a single hashtable, not an array of hashtables.  Use a comma in your return statement to force the return to go through as a collection:

```
,$aServers #| Out-Null
```

Just saw someone beat me to this in the comments.

Comment: I tried both and both didn't change anything. Please notice I am returning (expecting at least $aServers and not $importedData. I guess it returns number of Hash.Values of that 1 entry in $aServer. Hrmms

Comment: Okay, yes, I see the problem.  I looked at it too quickly.  The issue is that when you return $aServers, since there is only a single element, your parent calling process is receiving it as a single object, even though it is casted as an array.

Try this in your return:

,$aServers #| Out-Null

Comment: I've accepted it even thou the credit should go to Mathias but I guess he didn't bother ;-)